# Difference between (None, 2000, 8) and (2000, 8)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, dataset, machine-learning-model, training

Input: a tensorflow dataset with 17000 items:

```
<_TensorSliceDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(2000, 8), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(6,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
```

I receive errors, when I want to train a model.
The definition with the model starts with

```
# INPUT 
    inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2_000,8))
```

when I call

```
history = model.fit(dataset, verbose=VERBOSE,
                batch_size=32,
              epochs=1)
```

The Error comes:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 2000, 8), found shape=(2000, 8)

What is the difference between (None, 2000, 8) and (2000, 8)?
Why do these two not fit together?

How would I tune the model to expect the shape (2000, 8) ?
What would I have to do to the dataset to deliver the shape (None, 2000, 8) ?

Here is some code to reproduce the error:

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def create_dataset(items=100, features=8, datapoints=20, classes = 6):
   xdata = np.zeros((items, datapoints, features), dtype="float16")
   ydata = np.zeros((items, classes), dtype="float16")
   for i in range(items):
       xdata[i, :, :] = np.random.rand(datapoints, features)
       ydata[i, :] = np.random.rand(classes)
       
   return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xdata, ydata))

ds = create_dataset()

def in_block(x, filters, kernel_size):
   return tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = filters,
              kernel_size = 1,
              padding = 'same')(x)
   
def build_toy_model(datapoints, features, classes):
       
   # INPUT 
   inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(datapoints,features))
   
   ############
   # FEATURE EXTRACTION SUB MODEL
   inp2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(datapoints,1))
   x = in_block(inp2, 8, 3)
   x = in_block(x, 16, 3)
   model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp2, outputs=x)
   ###########
   
   all_chains = [model2(inp[:, :, i]) for i in range(features)]
   
   # COMBINE CHAINS
   y = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(all_chains)
   y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation='softmax', dtype='float32')(y)
   y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes,activation='softmax', dtype='float32')(y)
   
   # COMPILE MODEL
   model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=y)
   opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3)
   loss = tf.keras.losses.KLDivergence()
   model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer = opt)
   
   return model

model = build_toy_model(features=8, datapoints=20, classes = 6)

model.fit(ds)
```

Edit:
See [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/fabfabifabfabi/fit-issue/notebook)

Answer (score 1):

In short. This error disappears if you call

> model.fit(ds.batch(1))

See this post: [How to use tensorflow dataset to fit a tf.keras model? why do I need to batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78003396/how-to-use-tensorflow-dataset-to-fit-a-tf-keras-model-why-do-i-need-to-batch)

Comment: Links may not last forever, can you summarize the point you want the link to make in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

`(None, 2000, 8)` has an extra dimension, with the first dimension being the number of samples/observations. As can be seen [in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input#args), the `shape` argument of `tf.keras.Input` needs to be the shape of the data excluding the batch size. In your case, this would be `(8,)`.

Comment: so I have 17000 observation and each observation has the format (2000, 8). The Input of the Neural net also should have (2000, 8). I think that it relates to how to put the dataset into the fit method. In general it should work. It did work via a Simple Pipeline. But I am not happy with the documentation of those... https://www.tensorflow.org/ranking/api_docs/python/tfr/keras/pipeline/SimplePipeline

Comment: As [this answer on stackoverflow mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62878030/9435355), you need to get a batch of data from the dataset which you then pass to `fit`.